# How to set default message value for HTML select element?

Tags: html, css, html-select

I know an answer exists for setting a default value for an HTML select dropdown element.

```
<select>
     <option value="" selected="selected">an option value</option>
</select>
```

However, I need the placeholder to not be a 'choose-able' value. Such as 'Select a category'. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the default option:

```
<select>
    <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">an option value</option>
    <option value="">first choosable option</option>
</select>
```